# Is there an overview of your accounts on all Meta sites?

Tags: support, per-site-meta, network-profile

The stackexchange.com site has a nice overview of [all your network accounts](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=accounts), listing your reputation and  number of badges and posts on each site:

[image]

However, this overview is limited to main accounts. Does a similar overview exist for per-site metas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no such overview for per-site metas, but we can generate one with help of the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). Your reputation on those sites is the same as on the main sites, but it's also possible to generate a [virtual meta reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325798/4751173). [This SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1158606/meta-account-list) attempts to generate such a list; you'll need your global account ID, which you can find in the [URL of your network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current).

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Glorfindel, [your query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341046/282094) is a **lot** more complicated than the one written by @Rene that I [modified](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1083622/badge-count-across-the-network-to-match-what-would-be-your-flair-but-for-meta-si) to work for the child metas. You are more than welcome to tweak it. One modification you might want to make is that it only counts sites > 200 (to calculate 'meta Flair').

[image: Glorfindel's child meta reputation, on sites > 200]

Comment: It's more complicated solely because of the virtual meta reputation. That is a beast to calculate. I'll have a look if I can add a 'Flair' row as well, that is a good idea.

Comment: I've always disliked how the hard work on the child metas goes, for the most part, unrecognized; often it's important to the development of each site. At *least* the badges earned on child metas should be added to the Area 51 Flair Badge.