# Questions at two meta communities missing from my profile

Tags: support, profile-page, user-accounts, network-profile

I took at look at the information in my user profile, and it appears to be missing some things.

The list of accounts shows eight accounts with a total of 69 questions and 19 answers. But the list of "activity > posts" shows 71 questions and 19 answers. The two additional questions are one each in two meta communities:

- [Problem making sublists (or nested lists)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378386/problem-making-sublists-or-nested-lists)
- [Please reopen "PHP: Object for HTML hyperlink"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8943/please-reopen-php-object-for-html-hyperlink)

Are those communities not considered to be accounts (even though Meta Stack Exchange is an account), so that questions posted in them are excluded on purpose from the count of questions on the "accounts" tab of the profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=accounts) only shows main site accounts (and Meta Stack Exchange, which sometimes counts as a main site as well). AFAIK, this is by design; for most users, meta sites are not important. While your account on e.g. Meta Stack Overflow has the same ID and reputation as the main site account, it is technically a different account (its data is stored in a different database). So posts on per-site metas don't count towards the main account (they don't give you any reputation either).

Note that there are [ways](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341045/295232) to get an overview similar to the network profile for per-site meta accounts as well.

Comment: Thank you. I suggest adding a note at the bottom of the accounts tab saying that the list excludes per-site metas and linking to the information on how to get those data if one wants them.